# Vector made up of user defined type can't use vector::erase();

Tags: c++

Trying to make a simple card game program. I'm having trouble with the `vector::erase();` function on a vector made of of type `Card`. It seems that it can't use it because there isn't an overloaded function in `vector::erase();` that deals with a `<Card>`. This confuses me because a vector is `template`d.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

enum card_suit {SPADE, CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART};

class Card;
class Player;
class Deck;

class Card
{
    unsigned short rank;
    card_suit suit;
public:
    Card(unsigned short r, card_suit s)
    {
        rank = r;
        suit = s;
    }
    bool operator == (Card& a)
    {
        if(this->rank == a.rank && this->suit == a.suit) return true;
        else return false;
    }
};

class Deck
{
    std::vector<Card> cards;
public:
    Deck& add_card(Card c)
    {
        cards.push_back(c);
        return *this;
    }

    Deck& remove_card(Card c)
    {
        for(std::vector<Card>::iterator i=cards.begin(); i<cards.end(); i++)
        {
            if(*i==c) cards.erase(cards.begin()-i);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Deck& shuffle()
    {
    }
};

class Player
{
    Deck hand;
    unsigned short points;
public:
    Player()
    {
        points=0;
    }
};


int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you're encountering? Is it compile-time/run-time?

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code, but `vector::erase()` not being defined isn't one of them. Say what your actual error/problem is.

Answer (score 4):

This should generally work, provided you get the basic syntax and idioms right:

```
for (std::vector<Card>::iterator it = cards.begin(), end = cards.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
  if (c == *it)
  {
    cards.erase(it);
    break;
  }
}
```

Note that erasing from the container invalidates iterators, so we can only erase one element. We can't use the usual `erase(it++)` here, because all iterators beyond the erased one are invalidated by the erase.

In order to efficiently remove all matching elements from a vector, and you should instead use the remove+erase idiom:

```
cards.erase(std::remove(cards.begin(), cards.end(), c), cards.end());
```

This first reorders the elements of the vector so that all those that match `c` are at the end (`remove`), and then (efficiently) erases that end from the vector (`erase`).

Comment: Don't you think that my suggestion is better for this particular case?

Comment: @tyz: Well, if there's no requirement to maintain the order of elements, then you have a point, but rather than risking undocumented and surprising behaviour that other users of your code might not be aware of, I'd probably stick with remove/erase until there's a really good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If I do not miss something you just need to replace `cards.erase(cards.begin()-i);` with `cards.erase(i);`. Really I cannot understand what do you mean by that code.

Well, if to speak about effectiveness I guess that the card order makes no sense and we can use this feature:

```
std::vector<Card>::iterator i = std::find( cards.begin(), cards.end(), c );
if ( i != cards.end() ) {
    if ( i != (cards.end()-1) )
        *i = *(cards.end()-1);
    cards.pop_back();
}
```

*The suggested erase-remove combination results in copies of the vector tail.

Comment: This did it. I was assuming vector iterators worked like pointers to arrays, so I was attempting to subtract the address of the start of the vector with the address of where the value was found to find the sequential number of that value, which would then be removed.

Comment: @Bacu - Your code wouldn't have worked even if vector iterators worked like pointers into arrays and erase() took an index rather than an iterator. The expression `cards.begin() - i` results in either zero or a negative number, so it will only give the correct index in the case: `i == cards.begin()`. Pointers to arrays **do** act like iterators (but not necessarily the other way round), and the behaviour of iterators and pointers is very similar. The correct expression for the index is `i - cards.begin()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove just one card, then instead of this

```
        if(*i==c) cards.erase(cards.begin()-i);
```

do this:

```
        if(*i==c) cards.erase(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
cards.begin() - i
    //        ^^^^
```

The result of this expression is an ptr_diff.
While the erase() method takes an iterator.

Maybe you meant:

```
cards.erase( i );
```